# NODE.JS: CSS breaks for 404 page if I try to access a subfolder

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a CSS page which works fine for every page, including 404 in the views dir ( I am using NODE .JS alongwith express and ejs).

```
app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404');
});
```

CSS is included in the partials> header.ejs, which is included in every file in the views folder. I have
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` in the header, and `app.use(express.static('public'));` in the app.js file.
If I try to access localhost/about (about being non-existent) I get a custom 404 page with CSS applied.
However, I only get regular html text if I try to access localhost/about/help.
How can I stretch 404 to apply to any non-existent path?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/404', (req, res) => {
    res.render('404');
});

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/404');
});
```

does it. I am not sure if this is the most elegant way but serves the purpose though.